# Preserving partitions on clean Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-installation, windows-10-upgrade

I am going to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and I want to keep my hard drive partition and some files as it is now. Is this possible to preserve my current partitions on hard drive and files (which are not on Windows partition of course) performing clean installation?

Comment: If you want the free license you have to perform the upgrade, from within Windows, you can select the option not to keep anything if that is you desire.  It only touches your system partition.  You can also keep your files, then once it completes, reset the installation doing so is *exactly* what happens with a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

A clean installation of Windows 10 will place all your old files into a windows.old directory. It will not delete anything.

BUT, before you start, make sure to record your registration key. There are plenty of tools that can help, if you do not have it printed on a sticker on your PC. For example: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, while installing at partition selection, select which the partition you want to install,
Don't bother others partition